# Running PHP 5 alongside PHP 7 in Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have code from an old legacy site built in PHP 5 (which makes heavy use of `mysql_connect()`) that I'd like to get up and running. The only problem is that I'm hosting several other sites on the same Apache server, and they all use PHP 7. What's the best way to install PHP 5 and have this legacy site run using PHP 5, but to have all other sites running PHP 7?

I'm aware of why I may not want to do this but would still like to do it anyway.

Comment: Port that old code to more reliable, secure methods & libraries. `mysql_*` was deprecated for a reason, you're best to put in a few hours of work and get it up to scratch with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)/[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: If yor trouble only for mysql_* you can replace it to mysqli_* with pass connection.

Comment: PHP 7 only depreciates mysql, it hasn't removed it. It's still usable.

Comment: @KyleThomas You may be thinking of when it was depreciated in 5.5. It was removed fully in 7. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: True @Cal Then surely downloading the extension is possible or enable it in the php_ini

Comment: maybe interesting? run the PHP5 as a CGI program. not efficient but should work. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html. Also: http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/apjs06.html